# Cannot do checkbox event when adding li to ul in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to implement checkbox checked event, but seems cannot trigger it to new elements added to the list. Here is the jquery code.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("input[name=ListItem]").val();

    $("ul").append(
      `<li class="" id=` +
        generateID() +
        `><input name="name" type="checkbox" class="name" />` +
        listName +
        `</li>`
    );
  });

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      alert("Checkbox is checked.");
    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
      alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
  });

<ol>
<li id="1" class="">
<input name="name" type="checkbox" class="name"> List Name1 
</li>
</ol>
```

Thank you

Comment: probably need a delegated event listener

Comment: Can you show us the html elements?

Comment: I have another question, how to retrieve the id in a list as these ids are random numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Soluations for existing and new elements :**

```js
$('body').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
      if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
          alert("Checkbox is checked.");
      } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
          alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
      }
});
```

Comment: code only answers are considered poor quality

Comment: Hi @A.N. SINHA, thank you. I have another question, how to retrieve the id in a list as these ids are random numbers?

Comment: $('li').on('click', function(){  alert($(this).prop('id'));  });

Comment: I got undefined when getting the test var
$("body").on("click", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      let test;
      $("li").on("click", function() {
        test = $(this).prop("id");
      });
      console.log(test);
    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
      //alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }